# Only first key is available after "put"

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, flask-restful

I try to implement put handler for my resource. Here's the code:

```
class Settings(restful.Resource):
    def put(self):
        settings = request.form['settings']
        print settings
```

Here's how I put data there:

```
import requests
url='http://localhost:8000/settings'
data = {'settings': {
            'record': {
                'b': 'ok',
                'c': 20,
                'd': 60,
            },
            'b': {
                'c': {
                    'd': 3,
                    'e': 2,
                    'f': 2,
                },
                'd': 5,
                'a': 'voice',
                'k': {
                    'l': 11.0,
                    'm': 23.0,
                },
            }
        }
}
requests.put(url, data)
```

And there's only `record` printed out in my console when I do that so when I do validation, it fails because the data is not dictionary. I can't figure out what's wrong.

It looks the same as code in Flask-RESTful [Quickstart](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing), and if I get it right `requests` works with dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass in a dictionary as the `data` argument, `requests` encodes the data to ``application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, just like a browser form would. This encoding format does not support structured data beyond an (ordered, non-unique) key-value sequence.

Don't use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to post structured data. Use JSON instead:

```
import json

# ...

requests.put(url, json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Then in Flask use [`request.get_json()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.get_json) to load the payload again:

```
class Settings(restful.Resource):
    def put(self):
        settings = request.get_json()['settings']
        print settings
```

If you are using `requests` version 2.4.2 or newer, you can also leave the JSON encoding to the `requests` library; simply pass in the `data` object in as the `json` keyword argument; the correct Content-Type header will be set too:

```
requests.put(url, json=data)
```

Note that you then don't have to call `json.dumps()` yourself.